# How to apply subtraction in the query in laravel?

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

I have one array which contains all the records. I am passing all those records to a loop and there I am getting the sum of the clear column which has null upto.

This part is working fine, now my requirement is I want to add one more check which is based on the one more column `refund`.

If any column contains `refund=1` that amount should be subtracted from the total, can you please help me to achieve the scenario

```php
foreach ($row_data as $key => $value) {
    $data_arr[$key]['total'] = ['Price'=> $value->whereIn('clear', null)->sum('amount')];
}
```

**Data**

```
data = [
    {'amount' => 55, 'clear' => 'null', 'refund' => '0'},
    {'amount' => 5,  'clear' => 'null', 'refund' => '1'},
    {'amount' => 10, 'clear' => 'null', 'refund' => '0'},
];
```

Expected result is :-**60**

ACtual Result is :- **70**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reduce) should help.

```
$data = [
    ['amount' => 55, 'clear' => null, 'refund' => '0'],
    ['amount' => 5,  'clear' => null, 'refund' => '1'],
    ['amount' => 10, 'clear' => null, 'refund' => '0'],
];
```

You can be very explicit

```
// sum if refund is 0, substract if refund is 1
$sum = collect($data)
    ->where('clear', null)
    ->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
        if ($item['refund'] == '0') {
            return $carry + $item['amount'];
        } elseif ($item['refund'] == '1') {
            return $carry - $item['amount'];
        }
    }, 0);
```

Or write it a bit shorter

```php
// sum if refund is 0, substract otherwise
$sum = collect($data)
    ->where('clear', null)
    ->reduce(fn($carry, $item) => ($item['refund'] == '0')
        ? $carry + $item['amount']
        : $carry - $item['amount']);
```

You can even do it without collections using php's [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) functions. Works pretty much in the same way.

```
$sum = array_reduce(
    array_filter($data, function ($item) {
        return $item['clear'] == null;
    }),
    function($carry, $item) {
        return $item['refund'] == '0'
            ? $carry + $item['amount']
            : $carry - $item['amount'];
});
```

```
$sum = array_reduce(
    array_filter($data, fn($item) => $item['clear'] == null)
    fn($carry, $item) => $item['refund'] == '0'
        ? $carry + $item['amount']
        : $carry - $item['amount']
);
```

Comment: when using reduce () with ternary operator it's showing error ,expecting ,not =>

Comment: fn() =>  is php7.4 syntax. Maybe that's the error

Comment: Yes got it we are using 7.2php,thanks for your help I learn alot of things from your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all your code with variable declaration so I created logic snippet with your use case.

**EDIT:** You can simply get your total amount and substract you total refund as you can see in code below

```php
/** @var Collection $data */
$data = collect([
  ['amount' => 55, 'clear' => null, 'refund' => false],
  ['amount' => 5, 'clear' => null, 'refund' => true],
  ['amount' => 10, 'clear' => null, 'refund' => false],
]);

$totalAmount = $data->whereNull('clear')->sum('amount');

$totalRefund = $data->whereNull('clear')
  ->where('refund', true)
  ->sum('amount'); // = 5

$subValue = $totalAmount - $totalRefund
```

Comment: means i have to add price property subtraction logic ..?

Comment: I added where clause to take in case the refund filter

Comment: And I added the subtraction logic